# problems trying to use navsat_transform into robot_localization ekf_node

Tags: ros2, robot-localization, foxy

I'm using robot_localization from binary in foxy. I have an IMU, a magnetometer, wheel encoders and a GPS. I'm trying to integrate all of them into one odom message. I've already done that in the past on kinectic and ROS1, but now I spend a couple of days trying to understand the problem.
I fuse IMU (gyro + accel) and magnetometer data using imu_filter_madgwick, getting a new IMU message with earth's referenced orientation. I'm not using accelerometers on RL for now.
For testing purpose I made a node that suscribe to each sensor, overwrite covariance matrix with custom values and republish them, just to test different values of sensor noise. My test, rigth now, are statics one, that is with the robot fixed on the ground.
In order to isolate the probelm I made 3 launch file and 3 yaml file. The first one is for odomo to base_link and use imu and wheel odometry, I set world_frame: odom. In the second one I want to have map to base_link using IMU, wheel encoder and GPS odometry from a navsat_transform_node. The first test was whitout this information. In this ekf I set world_frame: map. Finally I launch navsat_transform_node using the IMU and the odomotry of the second EKF.
This are my config files:

```
ekf_filter_node_odom:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
        sensor_timeout: 0.1
        two_d_mode: true
        transform_time_offset: 0.0
        transform_timeout: 0.0
        print_diagnostics: true
        debug: false

        map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
        world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

        odom0: /chori/odom
        odom0_config: [false, false, false,   # x, y, z
                       false, false, false,   # roll, pitch, yaw
                       true, true, false,     # vx, vy, vz
                       false, false, false,   # vroll, vpitch, vyaw
                       false, false, false]   # ax, ay, az
        odom0_queue_size: 10
        odom0_differential: false
        odom0_relative: false

        imu0: /imu_filt/data
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,   # x, y, z
                      false,  false,  true,   # roll, pitch, yaw
                      false, false, false,     # vx, vy, vz
                      false,  false,  true,   # vroll, vpitch, vyaw
                      false,  false,  false]   # ax, ay, az
        imu0_differential: false
        imu0_relative: false
        imu0_queue_size: 10
        imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

        # odom1: /odometry/gps
        # odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
        #             false, false, false,
        #             false, false, false,
        #             false, false, false,
        #             false, false, false]
        # odom1_queue_size: 10
        # odom1_differential: false
        # odom1_relative: false

        use_control: false

        process_noise_covariance: [0.5, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.5, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]

        initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0, 1.0, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9]
```

```
ekf_filter_node_map:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
        sensor_timeout: 0.1
        two_d_mode: true
        transform_time_offset: 0.0
        transform_timeout: 0.0
        print_diagnostics: true
        debug: false

        map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
        world_frame: map           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

        odom0: /chori/odom
        odom0_config: [false, false, false,   # x, y, z
                       false, false, false,   # roll, pitch, yaw
                       true, true, false,     # vx, vy, vz
                       false, false, false,   # vroll, vpitch, vyaw
                       false, false, false]   # ax, ay, az
        odom0_queue_size: 10
        odom0_differential: false
        odom0_relative: false

        imu0: /imu_filt/data
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,   # x, y, z
                      false,  false,  true,   # roll, pitch, yaw
                      false, false, false,     # vx, vy, vz
                      false,  false,  true,   # vroll, vpitch, vyaw
                      false,  false,  false]   # ax, ay, az
        imu0_differential: false
        imu0_relative: false
        imu0_queue_size: 10
        imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

        # odom1: /odometry/gps
        # odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
        #             false, false, false,
        #             false, false, false,
        #             false, false, false,
        #             false, false, false]
        # odom1_queue_size: 10
        # odom1_differential: false
        # odom1_relative: false

        use_control: false

        process_noise_covariance: [0.00005, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.00005, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]

        initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9]
```

```
navsat_transform:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
        delay: 3.0
        magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0
        yaw_offset: 0.0
        zero_altitude: true
        broadcast_utm_transform: false
        broadcast_utm_transform_as_parent_frame: false
        publish_filtered_gps: true
        use_odometry_yaw: false
        wait_for_datum: false
        datum: [55.944904, -3.186693, 0.0]
```

Commenting the odom from navsat_node everithing works as expected:

```
/odometry/local:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1703877370
    nanosec: 618882913
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -3.265787509571813e-08
      y: -2.5325475992428667e-08
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.9464920648473698
      w: 0.3227270846721146
  covariance:
  - 105.41803562756589
  - 0.9999999997402413
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 8.97322730679937e-11
  - 104.41803562743078
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 9.97250753351147e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 9.945240794569202e-07
  - -8.99665850990115e-32
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 4.53524026675228e-32
  - 9.945240794569202e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.00045500753652848267
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: -5.0e-324
      y: -5.0e-324
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.016021900057577837
  covariance:
  - 0.003166571002366939
  - 5.0e-324
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 5.0e-324
  - 0.003166571002366939
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 9.958846128129104e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 9.838374544094523e-07
  - -2.133540770254387e-40
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0760776055407016e-40
  - 9.838374544094523e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0005829180548309103
```

```
/odometry/global:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1703877524
    nanosec: 533675418
  frame_id: map
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -5.5119621632357074e-08
      y: -5.058970622734353e-08
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.943614123552411
      w: 0.33104740722805115
  covariance:
  - 0.2039609652147536
  - 7.435771160987088e-10
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 8.815912973107209e-11
  - 0.20396096408126818
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 4.993807114645625e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 4.987659973458145e-07
  - 8.449250328203822e-33
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0860977782637455e-34
  - 4.987659973458145e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 9.300757210968958e-05
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: -5.0e-324
      y: -5.0e-324
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.01235058626604838
  covariance:
  - 0.003366571597252472
  - 5.0e-324
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 5.0e-324
  - 0.003366571597252472
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 4.990727864575202e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 4.963516746353309e-07
  - 7.982007752141765e-41
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -1.1567015083963526e-42
  - 4.963516746353309e-07
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0004669832570670235
```

```
/odometry/gps:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1703877582
    nanosec: 399740028
  frame_id: map
child_frame_id: ''
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -0.008271901635453105
      y: -1.2983679128810763
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance:
  - 0.010000000000000002
  - -1.727544254342965e-20
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - -2.1858820742247025e-20
  - 0.01
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.01
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
```

So, it seems that each node is consuming the correct topic.

The problem begin as soon as I un-comment odom1: /odometry/gps in 2nd EKF instance. Doing that makes the filter to diverge (?) and getting NaN in /odometry/global and tf errors on each nodes.

This are some sensor messages:

IMU:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1703877924
    nanosec: 612979324
  frame_id: base_link
orientation:
  x: -0.021131203593264605
  y: -0.00959170781407142
  z: -0.9435509779280431
  w: 0.3304134129041116
orientation_covariance:
- 0.0001
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0001
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0001
angular_velocity:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -0.0127901965752244
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 0.001
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.001
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.001
linear_acceleration:
  x: 0.42631348967552185
  y: -0.014370117336511612
  z: 9.81
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.001
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.001
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.001
---
```

Encoder:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1703878128
    nanosec: 55326030
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance:
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.0
  covariance:
  - 0.01
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.01
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
```

GPS:

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1703878190
    nanosec: 899551033
  frame_id: base_link
status:
  status: 0
  service: 0
latitude: -33.5079348
longitude: -60.0621127
altitude: 56.347
position_covariance:
- 0.01
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.01
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.01
position_covariance_type: 0
---
```

Do I missing something?

EDIT: I can't make the map to base_link to work alone even publishing fake /odometry/gps without runnning navsat_transform_node.
if I enable that message in the sensors list then the ekf_node broke as soon as I run it and print "Critical Error, NaNs were detected in the output state of the filter. This was likely due to poorly coniditioned process, noise, or sensor covariances"
But I can't find a good starting point to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime `NaN` values start to show up in your filter, there are really only two possibilities:

1. Your sensor data contains `NaN` values, or the covariance matrices in your sensor data are singular (or nearly so).
2. You are not measuring some part of your state that needs to be measured, and the covariance is growing without bound.

If I were you, I'd:

- Record a bag of everything in your system from bringup until you start getting `NaN` values/warnings
- Look at the state and covariance values of the EKF output leading up to the `NaN` reports. Are they stable, and then suddenly change to `NaN`? Are they increasingly unstable?
- Look at the input messages to the filter leading up to the `NaN` reports (look at the raw GPS as well)

Just a quick note: I'd avoid fusing absolute `yaw` from your IMU, at least in the `odom` frame EKF. I'd just fuse yaw velocity *and* wheel encoder yaw velocity. Not your issue, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank! I will try that and report back later. Can you elaborate why not fuse yaw in the odom frame EKF?

Comment: There's no real harm in it, but magnetometers drift/jump, and the `odom` frame is meant to be continuous.

Comment: ok, I understand. Oher question, the rotation of odom frame with respect to map frame is fixed and equal to (0,0,0) ?

Comment: At the start, but if you read ROS REP-105, you'll understand that the map and odom frames will drift from each other over time (or rather, if they do, that's fine).

https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

Comment: yes, I was reading that and I've noticed that my map - odom drift in position but not in orientation. So, I have some miss configured parameter. Maybe it has to do with use absolute orientation measurement on the odom EKF? I have no time now to test it until weekend. Thank Tom

Comment: The reason they are not drifting in orientation is because you are fusing absolute yaw from the IMU in both EKFs, which takes us back to the first point.

Comment: Thank Tom, it is working right now!